# Trying to plot a NO2 chart over different regions

Tags: google-earth-engine

What I am trying to plot is something like this:

[image: A plot of NO2 over different classes.]

Firstly, I classified my ROI into 4 regions (urban, vegetation, water and barren.) Then I extracted all four regions from the classified image. When I plot the chart I get an error like this -

> Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements.

```
var NO2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
    .filterDate('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
    .select(['NO2_column_number_density']);

var regions = [urban, vegetation, water, barren];

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: NO2,
    band: 'NO2_column_number_density',
    regions: regions,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 500,
    seriesProperty: 'label',
    xProperty: 'system:time_start'
});
print(chart);
```

Link to code:

[Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/93c213b19050e31482b9d120540674e7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the error message hint, you cannot have more than 5000 elements when you chart.

To get a separate series for each class, I believe you will have to manually turn your image collection into a feature collection, with a feature for each day and class.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2021-01-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2022-01-01')
var NO2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S5P/OFFL/L3_NO2')
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    .select(['NO2_column_number_density']);
var days = endDate.difference(startDate, 'days')
var dailyNO2 = ee.ImageCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, days.subtract(1))
    .map(function (dayOffset) {
      var date = startDate.advance(ee.Number(dayOffset), 'days')
      return NO2
        .filterDate(date.getRange('day'))
        .mean()
        .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
    })
)
var labels = ee.List(['Urban', 'Vegetation', 'Water', 'Barren'])
var features = dailyNO2.map(function (image) {
  var collection = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(image
    .addBands(classified)
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().group(1, 'class'), 
      geometry: ROI, 
      scale: 500,
      maxPixels: 1e13
    })
    .get('groups')
  ).map(function (properties) {
    properties = ee.Dictionary(properties)
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      label: labels.get(properties.getNumber('class')),
      date: image.date()
    }).set(properties)
  }))
  return collection
}).flatten()

var chart = ui.Chart.feature.groups({
  features: features, 
  xProperty: 'date', 
  yProperty: 'mean', 
  seriesProperty: 'label'
})
print(chart)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9c4a89b98eb7ed6ad009945052171b9d

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. But how do I plot NO2 concentrations for four regions (urban, vegetation, water and barren) in a **single** chart like [this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ktme.jpg)

Comment: I've updated my answer.